# Is there a module for raw graphics for python?

Tags: python, graphics

I need a module that is basically the most raw graphics possible
Just a window on the screen which I have random access to his pixels and have some basic events.
Is there anything like this?

Comment: Not in the built-in modules, AFAIK. You could try Pygame, which has low-level bit blitting capability. Or maybe you can do something with pywin32, and overload a window's WM_PAINT messages? Haven't tried it myself.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for [PyOpenGL](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net), which is the Python [OpenGL](https://www.opengl.org) binding. Keep in mind you should use another support library, like `Pygame` or `Tkinter` for showing your graphics.

Comment: After spending almost an hour trying to install pygame I gave up. I would recommend anything over it.

Comment: @ari What's your OS?

Comment: I spent the most time on my mac trying to get it to work, but I think I also tried to put it on my ubuntu

Comment: @ari Which version of Python are you using?

Comment: @ari If your version is 3, then watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L0Cl4Crg7FE) tutorial which will show you a workaround to install Pygame for Python 3 on a Mac.